# stored procedure exception handling in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, exception

Do i need to use try catch in my stored procedure to know where exactly in my procedure error has occured or can i achieve the same if i use`SqlConnection.BeginTransaction` in my ASP.NET form or simple try catch may be...???

I tried implementing try catch in my stored procedure..i m using sql server 2005 but it does not know TRY and CATCH keywords or ERROR_MESSAGE() function...i also installed sql server 2005 service manager but still it does not work..

if an error is thrown using `RAISERROR` method will the exception will be shown in my ASP.NET form??

Answer (score 1):

Surround the DB call in your code with the try-catch... try and put it at the level of the code-behind. If you are using a data access layer, put a try-catch there also, with a single throw statement. Then handle it in the code-behind when it bubbles up.

Answer (score 1):

To use TRY...CATCH within SQL Server look this manual: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

```
BEGIN TRY
     { sql_statement | statement_block }
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
          [ { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
END CATCH
```

You can catch the exception using catch (SqlException ex). You will find it in the System.Data.SqlClient namespace. You can also check the severity level.

Comment: note link in answer is in Portuguese, here is the US english link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx